# Hive with clause and join statement

Tags: sql, hive, common-table-expression

I'm have the following query and i am trying to join two statements that are grouping columns.

```
with ex as (
  select name, title,
  max(case when special = 'super' then max_power end ) as Super,
  max(case when special = 'awesome' then max_power end) as Awesome
from mytable
group by name, title)
inner join (select name, title,
  min(case when special = 'super' then max_power end) as Super,
  min(case when special = awesome' then max_power end) as Awesome
from mytable  mt
group by name, title) t2
on t2.title = ex.title;
```

I get an error of cannot recognize input near 'inner' 'join' ('in statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but the cte should be followed by another cte or a `select`, `insert`.

You can use

```
select name, title,
  max(case when special = 'super' then max_power end) as Super_max,
  max(case when special = 'awesome' then max_power end) as Awesome_max,
  min(case when special = 'super' then max_power end) as Super_min,
  min(case when special = 'awesome' then max_power end) as Awesome_min
from mytable
group by name, title
```

Use `union all` if the column names have to be the same.

```
select name, title,
  max(case when special = 'super' then max_power end) as Super,
  max(case when special = 'awesome' then max_power end) as Awesome
from mytable
group by name, title
union all
select name, title,
  min(case when special = 'super' then max_power end) as Super,
  min(case when special = 'awesome' then max_power end) as Awesome
from mytable
group by name, title
```

Comment: I need the super and awesome columns to be the same name because some might be coming in null before i join them.